# SSIS Connect Oracle 10g return error when create Datasource

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have installed Oracle 10g client (32 bit) on my OS Windows Server 2008 R2.
I am able to connect to Oracle server using Oracle SQL Plus.

But when i am connecting through Visual Studio BI (SSIS Data Source) 2008 R2. It is giving an

error:

```
TITLE: Connection Manager
------------------------------
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

In Datasource, i select Oracle Data Client Provider and fill tns service name in Server Name box.

Comment: Visual Studio is accessible to the Oracle client?

Comment: Do you have to use the ADO provider?  OLE DB is still recommended by Microsoft even on SQL 2012. I'd use the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" or the "Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity" (if you have SQL Enterprise Edition).